# VBA code to post cell value to textbox on a url without opening a browser

Tags: html, excel, url

I am new to VBA and need some help.

My code given below works, but I want to do the same without opening the browser: bot.Start "Chrome". The browser takes time to open and I want to work with the data transfer only to speed it up. I do not need the webpage to open.

```
Sub ConnectXL2()

'Dim bot As New ChromeDriver (This declaration was done as Public at the top of the Module, thus no    declaration needed here).

'Start Chrome, call url, maximize window

bot.Start "Chrome"
bot.Get "my url path here"
bot.Window.Maximize

'Give url time to load

Call delayms(500) 'This was also defined in a separate Sub.

'Find inputboxes and enter cell values

bot.FindElementById("site").SendKeys [A2]  'This enters cell A2's value in inputbox "site".
bot.FindElementById("room").SendKeys [B2]
bot.FindElementById("device").SendKeys [C2]

'Click Submit button on webpage

bot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/center/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/button").Click

'Wait for result to return

Call delayms(500)

'Get result value from reply textbox and enter it to a cell in Excel.

Range("D2").Value = bot.FindElementById("reply").Value

bot.Quit
Set ChromeDriver = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I do not understand this comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. – 
Community
What is not clear, or specific enough about my question?